# Split column with separator

Tags: python, pandas, split

```
| A             | B
| a;b;c         | 1;2;3
| a;b;c;d       | 1
```

In order to split the column , I am using

```
new = df["A"].str.split(";", n=5, expand=True).
df['A1'] = new[0]
df['A2'] = new[1]
df['A3'] = new[2]
df['A4'] = new[3]
df.drop(columns=["A"], inplace=True)

df['B1'] = new[0]
df['B2'] = new[1]
df['B3'] = new[2]
df.drop(columns=["B"], inplace=True)
```

Is there any other alternatives such that I do not need to count the number of data in each column??
I still need the output to be something like :

```
| A1| A2| A3| A4| B1| B2| B3
| a | b | c |   | 1 | 2 | 3
| a | b | c | d | 1 |   |
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to specify the number of splits as it will by default split on every instance of the separator. The result will be be a DataFrame where the columns are a RangeIndex, so add the column as a prefix. Loop over each Series (as it's Series.str.split) and then `concat` to join the results.

```
df = pd.concat([df[col].str.split(';', expand=True).add_prefix(col) for col in df.columns],
               axis=1)

  A0 A1 A2    A3 B0    B1    B2
0  a  b  c  None  1     2     3
1  a  b  c     d  1  None  None
```

---

Just be careful, the `'B'` columns contain strings `'1'` so if you want numbers used `pd.to_numeric`:

```
numerics = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('B')]
df[numerics] = df[numerics].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

  A0 A1 A2    A3  B0   B1   B2
0  a  b  c  None   1  2.0  3.0
1  a  b  c     d   1  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: What can I do if I dont want to add prefix on each col? For example I have a column called C which I don't need to split and I don't want it to change to C1

Comment: @YIPYIP then you can iterate only over stuff like `for col in ['A', 'B']` and concat the result of that back with whatever was in your original dataframe that you don't want to split.